# Expectation of stochastic differential equation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have solved the nonlinear stochastic equation $dX_t=\frac{1}{2}a(a-1)X_t^{1-2/a}dt+aX_t^{1-1/a}dW_{t}$, by reducing it to a linear one (change of variables $Y_{t}=X_{t}^{1/a}$ and applying Ito formula). The solution reads $X_{t}=(X_{0}^{1/a}+W_{t})^a$, however I'm stuck on how to compute the expectation $E[X_{t}]$. I am new to stochastic analysis so any kind of help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: @gt6989b I have tried the second approach you have mentioned and it does not go very far: I apply Ito's formula to $E[X^{1-2/a}]$ and cannot get an explicit solution as it equals $E[X^{1-4/a}]$ and so on... But I do have a question regarding your first approach as I haven't yet tried it: If I were to use the initial condition for $X_{0}$ as a constant, what would the integral be? I know for calculating the expectation it is integral of $xf(x)$ where f(x) is the probability distribution of x, however in this case x is $(X_{0}^{1/a}+W)^a$ so what would the integral be?

Comment: Assuming $X_0$ is a constant, you end up integrating
$$
\mathbb{E}[X_t] 
 = \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(X_0^{1/a} + W_t\right)^a \right]
 = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(X_0^{1/a} + z\right)^a f(z) dz,
$$
where $f(z)$ is the pdf of the $\mathcal{N}(0,t)$ distribution.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try this and see where it gets me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The distribution of $X_0$ should be given by some initial condition, typically it is a constant, but not necessarily and $W_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0,t)$ (i.e. the variance is $t$).

Then once both distributions are known, you have to take the integral.

An alternative approach, when the solution to the SDE is not easily derivable, is to take expected value of both sides of the original SDE, which kills the stochastic part:
$$
d\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \frac{a(a-1)}{2} \mathbb{E}[X_t^{1-2/a}]dt
$$
which is an ordinary differential equation.

Comment: @user4514 i'm sorry, i scanned the lecture briefly but didn't see it. Can you please let me know where exactly is the counterexample?

Comment: In general, the stochastic part cannot be 'killed by taking the expectation' (i.e. integral with respect to a brownian motion are not martingales in general): https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/08/16/failure-of-the-martingale-property/